# c++ UDP Win Linux

Tags: c++, udp

Я хочу создать обёртку над сокетами в виде 2х простых классов.
На подобии QTUdp.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qudpsocket.html

Но для его создания мне нужен рабочей код клиента и сервера удп.
У кого есть на примете РАБОЧИЙ код(лучшеб через std::.....)
UPD: мне нужен АСИНХРОННЫЙ ввод вывод.

То что я находил ещё с 90х годов и даже не компиллируется. Хотелосьбы чоб и на линукс код работал.
Использование boost не приемлимо!(ибо он 2 часа устанавливается да ещё и не с 1 раза).

Win компилю VS а линукс QTCreator.

Comment: Что значит "Сервер UDP". Сервер чего именно. UDP не гарантирует доставки и порядка доставки пакетов, по этой причине уже внутри самих пакетов кладут данные для обеспечения этого. Т.е. делают свой прикладной протокол поверх UDP, после чего этот протокол реализуют. И 95% всего кода зависит от придуманного протокола и UDP как такогового не касается. Поэтому никакого универсального сервера UDP быть не может. В качестве примера возьмите код любого TFTP сервера и клиента. Уж они точно компилятся, ибо работают на куче систем

Comment: Значит что рабочий код эхо сервера например. Мне известно что такое UDP. Мне не требуется готовый сервер подмою задачу мне надо рабочий код взаимодействия 2х приложений по сети.

Comment: Ну такое пишется минут за 15. готовый искать особой надобности нет. практически первое что дает гугл по запросу "udp echo" https://gist.github.com/suyash/0f100b1518334fcf650bbefd54556df9  выглядит вполне рабочим. конечно при компиляции на конкретной системе могут быть некоторые особенности с типами данных и их надо будет подправить.

Comment: Этот код не компилиться.

Comment: тогда у меня вопросы к вашему компилятору. У меня сходу компилится не выдавая даже ни одного предупреждения, ошибок то же не видно. Сделал просто файл cli.c занес в него тот код и откомпилил `gcc -O2 cli.c` И да, "не компилиться" ни о чем не говорит. могли бы хотя бы написать с какими ошибками. А лучше сами прочитайте ошибки и исправьте их

Comment: И да, если вы хотите сделать обертку, что бы она работала на разных ОС вам надо научится разбираться с этими ошибками. потому что системы все жутко не совместимы. Часто в портируемом коде приходится делать отдельные блоки кода, написанные для каждого отдельного компилятора на каждой платформе ... Особенно для windows у которого большие проблемы с POSIX-совместимостью

Comment: Если не принципиально, чтобы было на C++, можно на питоне в две строки udp эхо написать.

Comment: Онли с++. 
Ошибка error C1083: Не удается открыть файл включение: arpa/inet.h: No such file or directory

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков Ну так нет на вашей системе такого файла. Это нормальная ситуация. Комментарите строку, смотрите какие еще ошибки всплывут, на основе них понимаете описания каких функций не хватает, делаете блок условной компиляции, который на вашей платформе включит тот заголовочный файл, в котором описаны эти функции. Сразу предупреждаю, что некоторых функций на платформе windows нет и вместо них придется использовать какие нибудь функции из WinAPI, обычно начинающиеся на WSA.

Comment: на запрос "udp echo windows" гугл выдал такую статью http://taywils.me/2014/11/08/udpechoinc/  вот там как раз есть интересные вещи. типа для windows включается winsock2.h вместо нескольких файлов posix платформ

Comment: Ну и да, в той статье смотрю вообще предпочли для windows написать отдельные функции, потому что она слишком сильно не совместима со всеми остальными ОС.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В большинстве случаев, при переделывании простеньких линукосовых "сокет-проектов" в виндовые (таких как этот https://gist.github.com/suyash/0f100b1518334fcf650bbefd54556df9), нужно сделать следующее.

- удалить линуксовые заголовки

  ```
  #include <arpa/inet.h>
  #include <netinet/in.h>
  ```
- добавить виндовый

  ```
  #include <winsock2.h>
  ```
- добавить либу Ws2_32.lib в линковку или следующую строку в код

  ```
  #pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
  ```
- если при компиляции компилятор ругается на устаревшие функции вида `inet_ntoa`, в самый верх добавить дефайн

  ```
  #define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
  ```
- не забыть добавить вызов `iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);` ([пример](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms737593(v=vs.85).aspx)).

  (сервер после этого как минимум компилируется, линукуется и запускается)

Comment: Нет этого недостаточно.
recvfrom не принимает sockaddr_in*

Comment: не компилируется, падает, синий экран, розовый?

Comment: Ошибка error C3861: close: идентификатор не найден
Ошибка error C3861: inet_pton: идентификатор не найден

Comment: buffer[len] = '\0'; сервак скомпилился но крашнулся тк len = -1

Comment: на некоторых студиях похоже нужно ещё добавлять `#include <ws2tcpip.h>`. А close - это с клиентского кода - заменяйте на closesocket. А то что он падает - ну... это уже другое дело.

Comment: так я и просил код рабочий а не крашащийся такого я и сам найти могу.

Comment: клиент скомпилился и тоже крашнулся

Comment: добавьте проверку на -1. Это же не сложно.

Comment: а толку то? -1 значит еррор.
 WSAEFAULT от WSAGetLastError(); что означает что в коде что-то не так и он мне явно неподходит

Comment: кто то решил передавать нулевой размер структуры в recvfrom. поможет `int client_address_len = sizeof(client_address);`

Comment: Сервер перестал крашиться, но клиент также не работает. Больше я рассматривать этот код не буду. Он нерабочий и всё

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f7402dfa-405c-4b6d-95d8-3d10530d8120/using-server-and-a-client-with-udp?forum=Vsexpressvc этот код по крайней мере работает.